# Azure AD integrate with frontend React and backend GoLang

Tags: reactjs, azure, go, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have a separate structure for backend using GoLang Gin and frontend ReactJS and would like to integrate the Azure AD Oauth2 login.

However, it's ok to authenticate GoLang App or React App, but how to pass the auth info to the backend when I authenticate in frontend using msal-react?

In my current backend API, I use JWT like this to protect APIs:
`v1.Use(jwtauth.JWTAuth())`

or should I authenticate the backend and pass the info to frontend? but I cannot get it to redirect(Azure login) since they are in different port...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical pattern is:

1. Front-end (React app in your case) uses msal (or other compatible library) to redirect the user to login
2. Front-end acquires access token for back-end using a scope defined in API app registration (or same app registration)
3. Front-end attaches access token to back-end requests
4. Back-end validates access token (signature using public keys from Azure AD, expiry time, audience, issuer, scopes etc.)

In .NET we configure an "authority" for JWT authentication, e.g. "https://login.microsoftonline.com/", and the authentication handler then downloads metadata + public keys from "https://login.microsoftonline.com//.well-known/openid-configuration".
It might be possible to configure something like this for your library as well.
Scopes you typically have to check yourself.

Comment: Hi @juunas, I've tried two methods but cannot verify the access token, could you give me some suggestions? One is using "jwk.Fetch(c, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxx/discovery/keys")", one is using  "provider, err := oidc.NewProvider(c, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xx/")
var verifier = provider.Verifier(&oidc.Config{ClientID: "xx"})", it will show "token contains an invalid number of segments" or "crypto/rsa: verification error"

Comment: also, I tried to verify it on jwt.io with x5c, it also shows invalid. The token I created is with " msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(request)." from the React.js. Is that the right token for my backend?

Comment: What scopes are you using to acquire the token?

Comment: scopes: ["User.Read", "User.ReadBasic.All"]

Comment: Ok, that's an issue. Those scopes mean you get a Microsoft Graph API access token. You need to specify a scope defined in your API's app registration. That way you get an access token meant for your API.

Comment: I already added in the app registration:  Microsoft Graph (2)
User.Read
Delegated
Sign in and read user profile

User.ReadBasic.All
Delegated
Read all users' basic profiles

Comment: I mean you have to go to "Expose an API" page in your app registration and add a scope there.

Comment: I'll try it. So add in API permissions is not enough? not quite sure what's the difference...